# Why would a few files not let me copy/open/see properties?

Tags: windows-xp, filesystems

I have a few files that I recently put into a folder on a network drive.

When I try to move any folder that contains them, or the files themselves, I get a warning dialog box that just says `Cannot Move:` but no explanation after the colon. THe files themselves (one is a folder) cannot be opened like normal, and when I right click on them, the options it gives me are different (open, open with, send to, and scan for threat from the virus scan).. so no properties to check anything else about them.

Some of the files are FLVs that are linked to in another project and they play ok in that.. so all the data is there, but for some reason I cannot do any normal file management tasks on them

Very confused as to what could have happened to them

Comment: Is this a "normally" mapped network location (as in SMB share) or something like a mapped SharePoint workspace?

Comment: i'm honestly not totally sure how things are set up here (@work), I know I have it mapped and the filepath is like \\workgroupname\something\path\directory\file.extension

Comment: I wonder if [this issue](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15145/sp-2007-error-cannot-move-file-name-cannot-read-from-the-source-file-or-dis) is related. It sounds to me like it's not a "normal" file share. Knowing what service is mapped could help track down the cause.

Comment: I think it's just a regular SMB type share. not sharepoint as far as I know. I'll see what else I can find out (though will probably pass it on to IT in the end..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the file paths were more than 256 characters and Windows XP couldn't handle them.